# array to xml as a reuseable function

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I am trying to create a class where I can pass data as an array to `array_to_xml()` and ultimately have it spit out an xml formatted version of the Array in question. I seemed to have painted myself into a corner where nothing is being output, and I am almost positive its something in a sense minor that I am overlooking. So I need someone to assist me, give me a pair of secondary eyes.

Essentially I am trying to turn into a reusable function the answer found https://stackoverflow.com/a/5965940 provided by `Hanmant`.

```
function array_to_xml($arrayData, $xmlOutputName)
{
    $xmlOutput = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><".$xmlOutputName."></".$xmlOutputName.">");
    $theXML = $this->arrays_to_xmls($arrayData, $xmlOutput);
    $theXML->asXML();

}
function arrays_to_xmls($arrayData, &$xmlOutput)
{
    foreach($arrayData as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            if(!is_numeric($key))
            {
                $subnode = $xmlOutput->addChild("$key");
                $this->arrays_to_xmls($value, $subnode);
            }
            else
            {
                $subnode = $xmlOutput->addChild("item$key");
                $this->arrays_to_xmls($value, $subnode);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $xmlOutput->addChild("$key","$value");
        }
    }
    return $xmlOutput;
}
```

Comment: can you also add how you're using the `array_to_xml` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be so mad when you see this:

You just missed returning the value:

```
$theXML->asXML();
```

should be

```
return $theXML->asXML();
```